# How do I write descriptive statistics to the same CSV and TXT file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have ran descriptive statistics on a dataset but I have to write them to a CSV and TXT file. Here is my code so far in that section:

```
dfst=pd.DataFrame(sk)
print (dfst.describe())
dfstt=pd.DataFrame(ku)
print (dfstt.describe())

dfst.describe().to_csv('skewness_stats.csv',index=True)
dfstt.describe().to_csv('kurtosis_stats.csv', index=True)
```

The DF's run descriptive statistics on Kurtosis and Skewness simulations I ran. I am able to write the statistics to seperate CSV files, but how do I write them to the same one with column headers, etc.? Also unsure how to write them to the same TXT file. Any Ideas?

This is Python 3.10 by the way

Comment: did you look at the "IO Tools" section of the pandas documentation?

Comment: The answer is obvious, isn't it?  `print(dfst.describe(), file=myfile)`.

Comment: @Tim That was my first thought too. There's an existing question about that: [How to redirect 'print' output to a file?](/q/7152762/4518341)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you want the output of describe() or the dataframe as a csv, but anyway, simply use `to_csv` function of pandas:
For instance:

```py
dfstt.to_csv("kurtosis.csv", index=False)
dfstt.describe().to_csv("kurtosis_stats.csv", index=False)
```

If you want to tune your output, there are plenty of options you can use described there https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html (for instance, if you want the index or not)